# Making a private function public in C++

Tags: c++

I am learning my first programming language C++ and I have issues with making a private function public. Can you guys help me to find the problem?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class JadClass
{
public:
    void setName(string x)
    {
        name = x;
    }
    string getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
private:
    string name;
};
int main()
{
    JadClass jc;
    jc.setName = "Jad Charara w\n";
    cout << jc.getName();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, when you show me the private function I will try to help you.

Comment: `setName` is a method, not attribute. Call `js.setName("Jad Charara w\n");` instead of assigning.

Comment: As a side note, write `void setName(const string& x) ...` preferably.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I think he's having enough trouble without worrying about a little memory saving.

Comment: @Josh That's why it's marked as a _'side note'_ :P ...

Answer (score 3):

instead of

```
jc.setName = "Jad Charara w\n";
```

write

```
jc.setName("Jad Charara w\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have defined 2 functions in class JadClass with public access specifier,so please confirm access specifier of which function you want to change from private to public.

Second thing in main you are trying to call setName function.
jc.setName = "Jad Charara w\n";

The above function call should be in **jc.setName("Jad Charara w\n");** format.